# How to use between if value is not null?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Im trying to write query where im using valid_from and valid_to but those values can be null or one of them.

```
select * from omr_approval_teams where now() between valid_from and valid_to ;
```

This is my query, so i want to return data using if both `valid_from` and `valid_to` is null, or both not null or only `valid_to` is null. Any suggestion how can i achive that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just explicitly add passes for null date bounds:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM omr_approval_teams
WHERE (NOW() >= valid_from OR valid_from IS NULL) AND
      (NOW() <= valid_to   OR valid_to IS NULL);
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use a timestamp [range](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html) which automatically takes `null` as "unbounded":

If the columns are `timestamp` columns (without time zone)

```
SELECT *
FROM omr_approval_teams
WHERE tsrange(valid_from, valid_to, '()') @> localtimestamp;
```

If those two columns are `timestamp with time zone` you need to use:

```
SELECT *
FROM omr_approval_teams
WHERE tstzrange(valid_from, valid_to, '()') @> now();
```

The `'()'` parameter makes both edges *inclusive*. If you don't want that, adjust it accordingly.

Comment: That's usually the better solution, because that condition can be indexed easily.